# How to put differents colors in plotweb (bipartite package R)

Tags: r, colors, bipartite

I'm using the `plotweb` function from the `bipartite` package in R, to represent tropic relations. I have a problem with colors: I want a different color for each of my upper boxes, with interactions with the same color as the box from which it leaves.

This is my code, `x` is a contingency table.
I tried to attribute a color to interactions thanks to the sums of the columns: for example, if I have 3 interactions for the first column, my 3 first lines are with the same color but it doesn't work... `plotweb` seems to attribute colors randomly.

```
bipart <- function(x) {
  somme <- data.frame(margin.table(x,2))
  names(somme) <- c("eff")
  write.table(somme$eff, "essai.txt", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  effP <- scan(file = "essai.txt")
  colP <- rep(rainbow(length(effP)), effP)
                plotweb(x,
                              method = "normal", arrow="up.center",
                              col.high = colP, 
                              col.low = "black", 
                              col.interaction= colP, 
                              bor.col.interaction =colP, 
                              bor.col.high=colP,
                              bor.col.low="black",
                              high.lablength = NULL, low.lablength = NULL, text.rot=90,
                              text.high.col="black", text.low.col="black",
                              low.lab.dis=0)
}
```

And a part of my data :

```
atricapillum basilicorne blandulum carinatum confusum dubium
Cyperaceae 1 1 1 0 1 1
Juncaceae 1 1 0 1 1 0
Plantaginaceae 0 0 0 0 1 0
Poaceae 1 0 0 0 0 0
Typhaceae 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can use `dput(head(mydata))` to make it easier to reproduce your process.  ( `dput()` output can be copied&pasted into an R session to let others instantly get an example of your data)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to do !

```
bipart <- function(x) {
colP = rainbow(length(x[x,]))     
plotweb(x,
                              method = "normal", arrow="up.center",
                              col.high = colP, 
                              col.low = "black", 
                              col.interaction= colP, 
                              bor.col.interaction =colP, 
                              bor.col.high=colP,
                              bor.col.low="black",
                              high.lablength = NULL, low.lablength = NULL, 
                              text.rot=90,
                              text.high.col="black", text.low.col="black",
                              low.lab.dis=0}
```